# How to initiate a specific keystroke using automator?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, script

I have the following code :

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if application "KeyboardViewer" is running then
        quit application "KeyboardViewer"
    else
        activate application "KeyboardViewer"

    end if
    return input
end run
```

- I want to press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> automatically after I activate application so that I can start typing right away ..
- Reason to do this is because the keyboard becomes the foreground running application and the webpage or typing area the background.

Comment: In my answer, since you wanted to switch applications, I assumed you meant CMD+TAB as opposed to ALT+TAB. My answer reflects this assumption however, if this is incorrect please tell me and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Have you tried using launch instead of activate like in my answer to the [previous question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59875/how-to-open-or-toggle-keyboard-viewer-by-a-keyboard-shortcut/59891#59891)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `keystroke` scripting command available through the System Events application.

Add the following block to your script below (and at the same indent level as) the `activate`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab using {command down}
end tell
```

This will simulate <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and have the effect of switching applications.

To simulate the "ALT" modifier key, use `option` in place of `command` in the above.