# Show/hide Accessibility Keyboard with a keyboard shortcut in MacOS Catalina?

Tags: keyboard, catalina

I would like to display and hide the Accessibility Keyboard in MacOS Catalina using a shortcut.

The old solution from thread [How to show or hide Keyboard Viewer with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59875) is not working since the update to MacOS Catalina. KeyboardViewer.app is not anymore in /System/Library/Input Methods/

Comment: Are you trying to show the virtual keyboard or change keyboard languages?

Comment: Great question!  Keyboard Viewer is now the same as the Accessibility Keyboard, but I can't find the app you need for setting up a shortcut either.

Comment: This says the accessibility keyboard can be activated using option command f5.  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/accessibility-keyboard-preferences-mchlf6a6fc82/10.15/mac/10.15

Comment: Thanks Tom. That's unfortunately not ideal since you still need to click to activate the accessibility keyboard (for Macs with touchbar you can hit the Touch ID 3 times). I was hoping for an Apple Script solution but can't figure out how to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I found was to use "hot corners" to toggle the visibility of the virtual keyboard. Unfortunately this does require using the mouse, just moving it to a screen corner to activate a command.

You can access the hot corners tab from the accessibility keyboard settings (gear icon -> Preferences).

The "Hide/Show Home Panel" is the default and correct option. I like to unselect the "Panel follows Hide/Show Home Panel" so the Panel doesn't move around.

Note that this will only work if the accessibility keyboard is activated. This is definitely not ideal (a bit ironic too), but it's the least painful alternative I could find. Hope it helps!

Comment: It's actually unfortunate that @Shreyas Pai 's answer is the only answer that I can find. If anyone finds anything akin to an Alfred shortcut or a BTT shortcut, please let me know